# How to get last order status history comment and order status Magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1, sales-order, order-status, history

I need to change the order status and order status history comment based on the last value of the status, currently i've set order status and comment status like this:

```
$event = $observer->getEvent();
$order = $event->getOrder();
// need to check the previous order status history comment
$history = $order->addStatusHistoryComment('', $order->getStatus());
$history->save();
// need to check last order status
$order->setData('status', $order->getStatus())->getResource()->saveAttribute($order, 'status');
```

Comment: which observer you are using there?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To retrieve latest order's comment history you can do following:

```
$histories = $order->getStatusHistories();
/** @var OrderStatusHistoryInterface $caseCreationComment */
$latestHistoryComment = array_pop($histories);
$comment = $latestHistoryComment->getComment();
$status = $latestHistoryComment->getStatus();
```

To add new history comment to the created order you can use `Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Status\HistoryFactory` and `\Magento\Sales\Api\OrderStatusHistoryRepositoryInterface`:

```
/** @var \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderStatusHistoryInterface $history */
$history = $historyFactory->create();
$history->setParentId($order->getId())
    ->setComment($comment)
    ->setEntityName('order')
    ->setStatus($status);

$historyRepository->save($history);
```

Comment: thank you.. helpful

Answer (score 2):

Before adding the new status history comment you can get the previous one like

```
$statusHistoryItem = $order->getStatusHistoryCollection()->getFirstItem();

$status = $statusHistoryItem->getStatusLabel();

$comment = $statusHistoryItem->getComment();
```

Comment: If I wanted to change the order comments ordering from descending order (most recent on top) to ascending order (first comment on top) would this be possible using these methods? and if so, where would I do it? Thanks for the insight!

Comment: @Nikolas it is already most recent on top : 
$this->_statusHistory = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_status_history_collection')
                ->setOrderFilter($this)
                ->setOrder('created_at', 'desc')
                ->setOrder('entity_id', 'desc');